# Node Js - Solucinar Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: nodejs, multer

Estoy intentando subir archivos a un fichero local de mi proyecto, con node js utilizando multer, sin embargo me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\joshu_lmv4h9a\Documents\React_Proyects\cloudinary_gallery_app\backend\files\file-1629840895449.jpg'

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma

```
const path = require('path')
const multer = require('multer')

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '../files')
    },
    filename:(req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('Image Added')
    return res.send(req.file)
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las imágenes las intento enviar a la carpeta "files". Me gustaría saber como solucionar dicho error. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parece que es un problema con los paths. En tu error se ve que la ruta que multer espera es algo como _<proyecto>/backend/files/<file>_ y en la imagen que muestra la organización de los archivos del proyecto se ve algo como _<proyecto>/backend/src/files/_. Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, funcionó, solo tuve que sacar la carpeta de "src", podrías poner tu solución como respuesta y procedería a dar una votación.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que es un problema con los paths. En tu error se ve que la ruta que multer espera es algo como /backend/files/ y en la imagen que muestra la organización de los archivos del proyecto se ve algo como /backend/src/files/. Espero que te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En efecto es la ruta multer intenta guardar la imagen en
`/backed/files` pero tu files dir está dentro de src, para solucionar lo agrega esto

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, process.cwd()+”/src/files/“);
    },
    filename:(req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
```